# server failed to start while running a project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When i am starting my project with tomcat 6 , the server starts but after sometime it says server fail to start,but previously it was running fine & with tomcat 7 its running fine , so what is the problem?(i tried to add tomcat-juli.jar also but same problem)

Comment: after running the server it is saying in a window that server unable to start within 45 seconds

Comment: could you please update the exact error in the post.

Answer (score 0):

go to the servers view and check if your defined tomcat-servers load several applications at start-up.

if the servers do so, remove all applications, but the one you really want to start.
now both servers should start correct.

otherwise you may increase the timeout for start-up.

double click the server in the servers view and open timeouts. there you'll find values for start and stop, that you can change.

why?:
if you start an application, or several applications, that has to load a lot of information on startup and the loading/loadings is/are performed in the ServletContextListener(s) and it takes, in summary, more than 45 seconds, the error occurs

Comment: only 1 application is there, and  i had increase the time too still same problem. previously it was running fine in tomcat6 but now it is not. but is working with tomcat 7.

Comment: ok. are both servers configured with the same jdk/jre? in case of tomcat 7 it must be at least java 6. is the error displayed in a popup-window or written to the console? in my test-case it is displayed in a popup-window. have you changed tomcat 6's server.xml and/or context.xml for other applications? perhaps you could configure a further tomcat 6 at localhost and try to start the application on that ones.

Comment: already configure another tomcat 6,still same & the error was showing in popup window like sever failed to start type window.